# How to allow data to be visible and easily accessible even after closing the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a website so that a school can input a student name, chromebook serial number, grade and if the chromebook is in the school or distributed to a students home. I want to make the data accessible even if they close the window. How can I do this? Here is my form data below:

Form.js

```html
<div id="Form">
        <h3 className='form-header'>Add a new item to the table:</h3><br/>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleFormSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="laptopTag">
          Serial Number: 
          <input id="laptopTag" value={this.props.newLaptopTag} 
            type="text" name="laptopTag" maxLength="15" placeholder="ABCDE12345"
            onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} required/>
          </label>
          <label for="studentName">
          Student Name: 
          <input id="studentName" value={this.props.newStudentName} 
            type="text" name="studentName" placeholder="John Doe"
            onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} required/>
          </label>
          <label for="studentGrade">
          Student Grade: 
          <input id="studentGrade" value={this.props.newStudentGrade} 
            type="text" name="studentGrade" placeholder="6" maxLength="2"
            onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} required/>
          </label>
          <label for="status">
          Status: 
          <input id="status" value={this.props.newStatus} 
            type="text" name="status" placeholder="D/H" maxLength="1"
            onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} required/>
          </label><br/><br/>
          <button type="submit" value="Submit">Add Item</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

App.js

```html
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      laptopTag: '',
      studentName: '',
      studentGrade: '',
      status: '',
      items: []
    }
  };

  handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let items = [...this.state.items];

    items.push({
      laptopTag: this.state.laptopTag,
      studentName: this.state.studentName,
      studentGrade: this.state.studentGrade,
      status: this.state.status,
    });

    this.setState({
      items,
      laptopTag: '',
      studentName: '',
      studentGrade: '',
      status: '',
    });
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let input = e.target;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = input.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form handleFormSubmit={ this.handleFormSubmit } 
          handleInputChange={ this.handleInputChange }
          newLaptopTag={ this.state.laptopTag}
          newStudentName={ this.state.studentName }
          newStudentGrade={this.state.studentGrade}
          newStatus={this.state.status}
           /><br/><br/>
        <Table items={ this.state.items }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make the data persistent you can in the Browser world make use of Web Storage API called local Storage.

MDN Docs for LocalStorage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Other best option is to make use of NodeJS(or any server BE technology and use Database(like Mongo DB) to store data and get, post data back and forth via APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Quick question, how would I implement localStorage into the code above?

Comment: My Please Mate. This was too much to explain that's why, I kept it short. You seem to be passionate about coding. I am sharing this resource for you to get the idea about how to do it and you can learn so much more :) 

https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/

Enjoy coding dear. if you have any further questions. Just ping me here or on my linkidln. God willing tomorrow I will answer. It is too late in my country now and I got lot of work to complete :)

Comment: Thank you for your support, have a great night!